# Recommendation for a Wordpress Page builder with specific requirements

Tags: wordpress

I've been researching Page Builder plugins for Wordpress. The aim is to allow my users to select from several pre-built layouts (rows of content) and then choose the content that goes in these layouts.

The site is using Bootstrap, but the intention is that the user will select from pre-built HTML with bits to dynamically insert.

Most page builders that I have found on my search give the user too much control, selecting from column width, entering HTML, generating their own custom HTML, rather than just combining the blocks chosen by the user, using the predefined HTML for those blocks along with some data entered at page build time. For example:

- A block may be a two column layout, that is defined as HTML in the backend.
- The user selects this block and inserts it into a page.
- the user can select, for example, text to insert for the left column (some copy) and an image for the right using the media browser.

Can anyone recommend me a page builder that fits the following requirements:

- For a given Page, use the builder
- Select from available rows/widgets
- Insert a row into the page
- Select the content that goes into the row (e.g. content picker, insert content title, link, media browser for image, etc.)
- Page is built using pre-defined chunks of HTML with dynamic content inserted
- The pre-built HTML takes care of responsiveness etc, don't involve the user here.

Our site is high-traffic, so extra points goes to plugins that don't require lots of database hits at render time.

Comment: I assume you don't care about pricing? Does it have to use just the page builder (locks out the default editor)? Don't widgets allow plain text input that could act as HTML? Have you tried [Page Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/siteorigin-panels/) and [Visual Composer](https://vc.wpbakery.com/)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, neither allows me to have bespoke HTML as my blocks, they also appear to give the user too much control for resizing column widths etc. Happy to be corrected.

Comment: Page Builder (maybe Visual Composer too, I'm not sure, I haven't used it) allows you to place any widget, so you could presumably place a Text widget and add this bespoke HTML to that? You can also make quite a lot of changes through filters to disable things you might not want the user to control.

Comment: How about [Layers](https://www.layerswp.com/)? I think it takes care of some of the responsiveness but if it doesn't suit you you can change it.